# Make a text box automatically fill depending on drop-down selection (Laravel and Javascript help!)

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I am looking to automatically fill some text boxes in a page depending on what the user selects from the dropdown on the same page.

So like, if a user makes a selection then auto fill related information from the database. And then if a user changes the selection, dynamically update and change the information in the text boxes to match the selection.

So far all I can do is display some database text if I hard code the selection (which of course just displays the same thing no mater what the users does).

Say I am pulling some information from a specific field called info_description in my database:

```
$fill = \DB::table('tbl_information')->where('id', 1)->pluck('info_description');
```

which is passed to the blade.php file like this:

```
return view('pages.information')
        ->with('fill', $fill);
```

and I have the following in my blade.php file

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">app method</label>
    <div class="col-md-6 input-group-sm">
        {!! Form::text('text', $fill) !!}
    </div>
</div>
```

I figure I need some JavaScript to help me with this but I am completely lost as to how to go about it. I could really use some help and direction if anyone can guide me on this.

How can I make this work?

Comment: You want to pull `info_description` for `id` 1,2,3,4..etc when user selects any of these?

Comment: Yes, exactly that! and auto fill the text box without needing to refresh the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give you a head start.

**route.php**

```
Route::get('/infos/{id}', 'InfoController@getInfo');
```

**InfoController.php**

```
public function getInfo($id)
{
  $fill = \DB::table('tbl_information')->where('id', $id)->pluck('info_description');

  return Response::json(['success'=>true, 'info'=>$fill]);
}
```

**app.js**

```
$("#info_id").change(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/info/' + $(this).val(),
    type: 'get',
    data: {},
    success: function(data) {
      if (data.success == true) {
        $("#info_id").value = data.info;
      } else {
        alert('Cannot find info');
      }

    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {}
  });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<select name="info_id" id="info_id">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
<textarea name="info_area" id="info_area" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```

Comment: Thank you. I will have a go at this. This is my first laravel project and currently I haven't got a JavaScript file. What folder should I be creating one in?

Comment: You can add your file here. `public/js/app.js` You'll have to create a folder for `js` inside public folder..

Comment: This definitely helps me, I've upvoted but I haven't got enough rep points for it to display yet